# Firebase function winston logging severity

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver, winston

I'm using firebase functions (node 10 Beta) with winston.

I've the console transport configured and my logs are going to stackdriver.

They're coming as `textPayload` without severity level, is there any config that I'm missing?

I achieved this using node 8 with [loggin-winston](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-winston) transport, which I think is not recommended.

[working] Node 8:

```js
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new LoggingWinston(),
  ],
});
```

Deps:

```
"@google-cloud/logging-winston": "^3.0.4"
"winston": "^3.2.1"
```

Stackdriver console:
[image]

[not working] Node 10 beta:

```js
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new LoggingWinston(),
  ],
});
```

Deps:

```
"@google-cloud/logging-winston": "^3.0.4"
"winston": "^3.2.1"
```

Stackdriver console:

[image]

[Sample repo](https://github.com/ndeitch/sample-ms) - deploy it on node8 and node10 to check the differences

Comment: Can you share the code which you are using to write the logs to Stackdriver? It would be easier to identify the issue with this information

Comment: so its working on Node8 but not on Node10 ? have you tried Node12 ?

Comment: Is it supported? [as doc says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) only node 8 and 10 (beta) are supported

Comment: I think this is a result of Node 10 still being in beta, I would suggest you to send some feedback through the [Public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for the Stackdriver logging

Comment: Take a look at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124403972